# Font color won't revert back to orginal color

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

The event only carries out one way and for some reason not the other way when the variable is clicked again.

I have multiple other events carrying out on the same variable and they all work perfectly fine. However, when it comes to this it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

```
//Font color change
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (li[i].style.color == '#4D5067') {
            li[i].style.color = '#C8CBE7'
        } else {
            li[i].style.color = '#4D5067'
        }
     })
}
```

Comment: Try changing `li[i].style.color` to  `e.target.style.color`

Comment: Don't switch colours, switch class-names.

Answer (score 1):

Set the colours in CSS, and then use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle between the classes.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick({ target }) {
  target.classList.toggle('light');
}
```

```css
li { color: #4D5067; }
li.light { color: #C8CBE7; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test1</li>
  <li>Test2</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
  <li>Test4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've toggled between class names and it works